# UTF8 problem sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some utf8 data which I would like to bulk insert (sql server 2005). I am using the CODEPAGE 65001:

```
BULK INSERT #bla
FROM 'D:\bla.txt'  
WITH 
( 
    CODEPAGE=65001,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Unfortunatly strings like this:

Erdağı

end up being stored like this:

Erda??

Do I use the wrong code page? Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: How certain are you that it's *genuinely* a UTF-8 file? And how are you looking at the stored data? See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/DebuggingUnicode.aspx for a general approach to this.

Comment: This is the data source: http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=&men=stdl&lng=en&des=wg&srt=npan&col=abcdefghinoq&msz=1500 they say it is UTF 8 and I can see the correct string in UniRed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), "SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)." At first, I thought this related only to 2008, but according to a Microsoft technical writer's response to a question on [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001?wa=wsignin1.0), "SQL Server never has supported code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)."

Comment: Interesting and very disappointing. I originally obtained the code page from one of these sites – they must have changed something. Are you aware of a work around?

Comment: It seems to like UCS-2 and you can translate UTF8 to UCS-2. Has anyone done this succesfully?

Comment: I have managed to translate UTF8 to UCS-2 (there may be some information loss though). Note that you should use nvarchar whilst importing as well.

Comment: The UCS-2 encoding used by SQL Server *always* uses exactly two bytes per character. Therefore, it can only encode characters in Unicode's so-called "Basic Multilingual Plane". It is therefore unable to natively encode any Unicode characters outside that plane. Note that UTF-16, which is similar, and *usually* uses two bytes per character, avoids that limitation by using four bytes per character for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. The UTF-8 encoding is similar in that it can represent any Unicode character using two and four byte characters. As you've discovered, UCS-2 cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You may use c# to handle this problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UTF8toUCS2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exampe: UTF8toUS2 [filepath]");
                return;
            }

            var filename = args[0];

            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

            byte[] newArray = new byte[content.Length + 3];

            newArray[0] = (byte)0xEF;
            newArray[1] = (byte)0xBB;
            newArray[2] = (byte)0xBF;

            Array.Copy(content, 0, newArray, 3, content.Length);

            byte[] utcs2Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, newArray);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, utcs2Bytes);
       }
    }
}
```