# transform UT8 to UCS-2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have recently learned that sql server 2005 does not support UTF8:

[UTF8 problem sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336992/utf8-problem-sql-server)

I believe it supports UCS-2 though and look for a way to transform UTF8 to UCS-2 without loss of information if possible. Is it?

Any feedback would be very much welcome. Thanks!

Christian

PS: C# preferred (-:

Comment: Note, it is not possible to convert full UTF-8 to UCS-2 as UCS-2 does not support full range of Unicode, but only BMP (i.e. codepoints 0-0xFFFF). So you may loos some information. If you convert to UTF-16 (UCS-2 is subset of UTF-16) you keep all information, but looks Sql-Server would not be able treat such characters (outside of BMP) correctly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805259/storing-utf-16-unicode-data-in-sql-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a text file encoded in UTF-8 and you want to re-encode it to UCS-2. `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` support encoding automatically; you supply an `Encoding` object in their constructors.

You should be able to:

1. Construct a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx) with [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx)
2. Construct a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx) with [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx)
3. Read lines from the reader and write them to the writer